# Path's fillOpacity in openlayers won't work

Tags: path, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm drawing a polygon with OpenLayers on my OSM map.
After all neccessary things i'm executing these lines:

```
polygonFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
                new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linear_ring]), null, style_green);
```

where style_green is

```
var style_green =
{
    strokeColor: "#000000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.3,
    strokeWidth: 1,
    fillColor: "#00FF00",
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
};
```

but for some reason strokeOpacity and fillOpacity don't work, showing me solid polygon:

[image]

However, html properties of path, that's created by the openlayers code, looks legit:

[image]

How can I fix this thing?

Comment: I don’t see any reason, except if you have multiple instances of the same shape in the same place. Are you sure to have a single feature at that place?

Comment: godamnit! that was error in a cycle.